# Child over 13 cannot access Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-account, passwords

I created a Gmail account for my sister when she was under 13. Gmail blocked it so we left it as is until she turned 13. Now that she's 13, we cannot access it and it asks verification questions that we never gave it or did not get the chance to (as we were blocked).

How do I get access to that account again?

Comment: Is it possible that the username was recycled and now belongs to someone else?

Comment: I'm not sure of the protocols Google has in place. That could very well be the case, but I'm asking in case anyone knows something I don't.

Comment: Well, if Google is asking you security questions which you didn't set up, it seems (to me) likely. The answer to [this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86947/recover-google-account-when-someone-changed-the-phone-number-and-the-email-addre) might be helpful.

Comment: I'm guessing so too. Thanks for the link @AlE. Will post back if I get anywhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover my Google password or username?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/52706/how-do-i-recover-my-google-password-or-username)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to accomplish this if the account has not actually been claimed/hijacked/deleted is to clear your browser cache and cookies then restart your browser.  This would clear the cached data and cookies that Google sets to let it know of your previous answer to the age question.

On almost all modern browsers a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> (Mac) will bring up the menu that contains the options to clear your cache, cookies, history, etc.